# x86 ELF Disassembler that disassembles to Intel Syntax

Tags: linux, x86, elf, disassembly

Is there a Disassembler that runs on Linux that has the capacity of disassembling x86 ELF executables to assembly code in the Intel syntax (i.e. *operation destination register, source register*; etc.)? Preferably the output disassembler would be fairly close to the NASM syntax. `objdump -d` works fairly well, but outputs the AT&T syntax that I sometimes find difficult to follow, and `ndiasm` only disassembles straight binary to my knowledge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can tell `objdump` to use Intel syntax:

`objdump -M intel -d`

Answer (score 1):

You might find ODA useful.  It's a web-based disassembler that supports tons of architectures.  And yes, it supports supports both AT&T and Intel syntax for x86.

http://onlinedisassembler.com/